# How remove duplicated blocks using notepad++ or other tool?

Tags: regex, notepad++, duplicates

How do i remove duplicates from a file. Not are simple lines, but are blocks.

I have a big list like this:

```
define service {
    param1                                          ABC
    param2                                          XYZ
    param3                                          123456
}

define service {
    param1                                          KBW
    param2                                          XYZ
    param3                                          100100
}

define service {
    param1                                          PYJ
    param2                                          XYZ
    param3                                          99842
}

define service {
    param1                                          ABC
    param2                                          XYZ
    param3                                          123456
}

define service {
    param1                                          KBW
    param2                                          XYZ
    param3                                          100100
}
```

I need to remove the duplicated entries, in this example, the blocks with param1=ABC and param2=KBW. I know how do this to remove lines, but with block i dont know do.

Comment: 1) in your example, no dups found for your criteria `param1=ABC and param2=KBW` param2 is a typo? 2) remove the dups means leaving one block as unique there? or if there is duplicates found, all blocks same as dup should be removed? 3) other tools? are vim/awk/perl/... counted in? given the example, awk could solve it easily.

Comment: Using PHP, you could do the following `$string = implode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, array_unique(preg_split('/(?<=})(\r\n?|\n)+(?=\w)/', $string)));echo $string;` [demo](http://codepad.org/axUoApXs).

Comment: Kent, i need to keep only one occurrence and remove the others duplicated blocks. In this example, the 4th and 5th blocks must be eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
find: (define service \{.*?\})(.*?)\1
replace: $1$2
```

but you must push the replaceAll button until there is no more matches.

Comment: @dellasavia: It works! tested with your example string in notepad++6.3.2 with dotall option checked (the dot can match newlines)

Comment: Oh, sorry! It is true! My notepad was outdated! I'll run as many times as necessary, correct? Solved my problem! Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically, as often as necessary, until the end of the file? Are 35,000 blocks.

Comment: @dellasavia: Not with notepad++ as far i know. But you could use php or java to load your file and apply a regex with much possibilities.

Comment: i tested in my file, was doing well, but it seems that removed more blocks than it should. I have not figured out how it occurs, I will do more tests.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with `Notepad++`. With your file open press `CTRL+H` to open the `Replace` dialog box.

In `Find what:` input the following regex for `ABC`

```
define service \{\s+param1\s+ABC[^}]+\}
```

`Replace with:` would remain empty because we want to remove our selections. Select `Regular expression` radio button and `Matches newline` checkbox as well.

Then click on `Find Next` for the first occurrence. Click again to **skip** this one. From there on simply click `Replace` to replace duplicates. **Do not** click `Replace All` as it will replace the first occurrence as well. Now, repeat the same process for `KBW`

```
define service \{\s+param1\s+KBW[^}]+\}
```

Comment: Ravi Thapliyal, i have many other events and do not know what to say. It is a file with 35,000 blocks, and many are duplicates. It would take a regex that did not need to define what the content of param1