# Remove Duplicate XML blocks using Notepad++

Tags: xml, duplicates, notepad++

I have a large XML file and trying to remove duplicate blocks of XML (keeping the first occurrence only). I have found conflicting posts if using regex can accomplish this in Notepad++

```
<mms date="12345678" rr="123" sub="blah" ct_t="blahblahblah" address="123" readable_date="Jan 01, 2022 00:00:00 PM" contact_name="(blah)">
    <parts>
      <part seq="0" ct="image/jpeg" name="blah" data="ABC" />
    </parts>
    <addrs>
      <addr address="123" type="137" charset="106" />
      <addr address="345" type="151" charset="106" />
    </addrs>
  </mms>
  <mms date="12345678" rr="123" sub="blah" ct_t="blahblahblah" address="123" readable_date="Jan 01, 2022 00:00:01 PM" contact_name="(blah)">
    <parts>
      <part seq="0" ct="image/jpeg" name="blah" data="ABC" />
    </parts>
    <addrs>
      <addr address="123" type="137" charset="106" />
      <addr address="345" type="151" charset="106" />
    </addrs>
  </mms>
  <mms date="12345678" rr="123" sub="blah" ct_t="blahblahblah" address="123" readable_date="Jan 01, 2022 00:00:00 PM" contact_name="(blah)">
    <parts>
      <part seq="0" ct="image/jpeg" name="blah" data="XYZ" />
    </parts>
    <addrs>
      <addr address="123" type="137" charset="106" />
      <addr address="345" type="151" charset="106" />
    </addrs>
  </mms>
  <mms date="12345678" rr="123" sub="blah" ct_t="blahblahblah" address="123" readable_date="Jan 01, 2022 00:00:01 PM" contact_name="(blah)">
    <parts>
      <part seq="0" ct="image/jpeg" name="blah" data="XYZ" />
    </parts>
    <addrs>
      <addr address="123" type="137" charset="106" />
      <addr address="345" type="151" charset="106" />
    </addrs>
  </mms>
```

After find/replace it would look like this (essentially looking for duplicates in the data="" section of the XML to match ignoring everything else if possible)

```
  <mms date="12345678" rr="123" sub="blah" ct_t="blahblahblah" address="123" readable_date="Jan 01, 2022 00:00:00 PM" contact_name="(blah)">
    <parts>
      <part seq="0" ct="image/jpeg" name="blah" data="ABC" />
    </parts>
    <addrs>
      <addr address="123" type="137" charset="106" />
      <addr address="345" type="151" charset="106" />
    </addrs>
  </mms>
  <mms date="12345678" rr="123" sub="blah" ct_t="blahblahblah" address="123" readable_date="Jan 01, 2022 00:00:00 PM" contact_name="(blah)">
    <parts>
      <part seq="0" ct="image/jpeg" name="blah" data="XYZ" />
    </parts>
    <addrs>
      <addr address="123" type="137" charset="106" />
      <addr address="345" type="151" charset="106" />
    </addrs>
  </mms>
```

I tried to model my regex from [this post]([How remove duplicated blocks using notepad++ or other tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802311/how-remove-duplicated-blocks-using-notepad-or-other-tool) but wasn't able to find a way.

Comment: First you say you want to remove duplicate elements, then you seem to say you want to remove everything except the duplicates. Which is it? Either way, regular expressions are not the way to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How remove duplicated blocks using notepad++ or other tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802311/how-remove-duplicated-blocks-using-notepad-or-other-tool)

Comment: Show your attempts using the regex provided in the duplicate.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  My goal is to remove the whole xml block between <mms></mms> if the data="ABC" part is the same as any other block. No other element in the block matters.  I would only like to use Notepad++ to do the find an replace and tried the following but did not work:

(<mms \{.*?\</mms>)(.*?)\1

I dont think i've formed this correctly, nor am I sure if you can accomplish what i'm looking to do in Notepad++ only.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this as an XSLT grouping problem:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0" xmlns:f="urn:f">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="//mms" group-by="f:key(.)">
    <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) > 1">
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="f:key" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="node" as="element(*)"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="serialize($node, 
    map{'method':'xml', 
        QName('http://saxon.sf.net/', 'canonical'):true()})"/>
</xsl:function>

</xsl:transform>
```

The grouping part is easy (and is easily adapted if you want to discard duplicates rather than retaining only the duplicated records). The difficult bit is computing a grouping key. What I have done here is to use the canonical XML serialization of the element as its grouping key. The downside is, this uses a feature that's only available in Saxon Professional Edition. If you don't want to pay for that, you could write your own canonicalization function, or use the normal XML serialization - the only downside of that is, it doesn't guarantee to output namespaces and attributes in a standard order, which means that it might not detect duplicates correctly.